# How to represent semnet in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, semantic-web

I am trying to create a semantic network that looks a bit like this: [image: this].

So far I have just set up the basic facts, such as `isa(man,person)` or `hasa(person,node)`.

If I create instances of a Person, such as `isa(mark,father)` and then look up `height(mark,Height)` I get false. I understand that I have to somehow further develop the definition for `height(Person,Height)` as well as `isa(X,Y)` and `hasa(X,Y)` but am unsure how to go about this.

What I would like to happen is to be able to be able to look up, for example, `height(mark,Height)` and get `195`, or `hasa(mark,X)` and get `body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first issue you need a rule with variables. In words you can specify the rule like

*If X is of type T and things of type T have height H then X has height H.*

in this case

*If mark is a father and fathers have height 195 then mark has height 195.*

In Prolog:

```
height(X,H) :- isa(X,T), height(T,H).
```

For the second issue you need a recursive rule. In words:

*If X is of type T and things of type T have element E then X has element E.*

Rephrased:

*X has element E if X is of type T and a thing of type T has element E.*

You can see from the second statement that the rule for *has element* contains itself in the definition. This is recursion, and it allows the rule to expand itself automatically into multiple levels. In the current example the first expansion would be:

*X has element E if X is of type T and a thing of type T is of type Z and a thing of type Z has element E.*

In the example this would be:

*X has a body if X is a father and a father is a man and a man has a body*.

This expansion can continue as long as there are `isa` statements with the right values available (in this case we need one more expansion). The last expansion does not use the rule but matches on a simple fact (in this case `hasa(person,body)`). In prolog:

```
hasa(X,E) :- isa(X,Z), hasa(Z,E).
```

Full example:

```
% isa: general facts
isa(father,man).
isa(man,person).
% isa: specific facts
isa(mark,father).
% height: general facts
height(father,195).
% height: rules
height(X,H) :- isa(X,T), height(T,H).
% hasa: general facts
hasa(person,body).
% hasa: rules
hasa(X,E) :- isa(X,Z), hasa(Z,E).
```

Queries:

```
?- height(mark,Height).
Height = 195 .

?- hasa(mark,X).
X = body .
```